# Neo4j strange behavior

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j Desktop. All was well until today when the display of the nodes and edges started showing to anomalous *(857728) node and similar item in edges. I went to my backup and saw the same anomaly. Tried other databases with similar results. On occasion, the node and edge type do not appear until I run a query.

I considered re-installing Neo4j desktop. But I do not know how to retain my databases. How do you add a previously created database to a new project?

[image]

Comment: Aren't they Blank Nodes?

Comment: No, that's what is really weird. When I click on *(857728), I get a mix of 3 node types: KitNode, PosNode and SNPNode. When I click on *(643720) I get a set of KitPos nodes.

Comment: When I run these queries, I get a single return:

match (n) where id(n)=857728 return n

match ()-[r]->() where id(r)=6434720 return r

Comment: it's just the total number of node (and relationship) you have in the database. In fact it's the same behaviour than on the panel query.